# how do I make this compile?

Tags: java

This is my code snippet:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class chatboxServer {
  JFrame fr;
  JPanel p;
  JTextArea ta;
  JButton send;

  chatboxServer() {
    fr=new JFrame("ChatBox_SERVER");
    p=new JPanel();
    ta=new JTextArea();
    ta.setRows(20);
    ta.setColumns(20);
    send=new JButton("send");
    fr.add(p);
    p.add(ta);
    p.add(send);
    fr.setVisible(true);
    fr.setSize(500,500);
    fr.setResizable(false);
    try {                                    // Making server listen to port number 3000
      ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(3000);
    } catch(Exception exc) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"Cannot Listen :3000");
    }
    try {
      Socket s=null;
      s=ServerSocket.accept();
    } catch(Exception exc)
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"Accept Failed :3000");
    } 
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new chatboxServer();
  }
}
```

The error that I get is:

> Non static method cannot referenced from static context.

Please explain how can I can make this compile?

Comment: This is not a bug, it's a feature!

Comment: Next time, tell us what line the compiler error happens.

Comment: @Hernán Eche then what is a bug?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug

Comment: @Suhail Gupta, a bug is subjetive, a compile error is objective, a compiler can detect a compile error (for example grammar, spelling..), but bug refers to an undesired operation, then compiler can't know your desires, still...

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that in the line `s=ServerSocket.accept()` you're trying to call `accept` on the `ServerSocket` class rather than on an instance of the class. [accept](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29) is an instance method not a static method.

You probably want something like:

```
ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(3000);
Socket sock = s.accept();
```

Possibly just wrapping these in a single `try/catch`. e.g

```
ServerSocket serverSocket;
Socket socket;
try {              
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3000);
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Cannot Listen and accept on port 3000");
}
```

Comment: @Suhail so is the problem fixed now?

Comment: @Suhail - no, you have not - at least not in the code posted in the question: `ServerSocket` is not the same as `serverSocket` (Java is case-sensitive)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class chatboxServer
{
    protected JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();;
    protected JButton send;
    protected JFrame fr = new JFrame("ChatBox_SERVER");
    protected JPanel p = new JPanel();

    chatboxServer()
    {
        ta.setRows(20);
        ta.setColumns(20);
        send = new JButton("send");
        fr.add(p);
        p.add(ta);
        p.add(send);
        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.setSize(500, 500);
        fr.setResizable(false);
        ServerSocket s = null;

        try
        { // Making server listen to port number 3000
            s = new ServerSocket(3000);
        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Cannot Listen :3000");
        }

        Socket sock = null;

        try
        {
            sock = s.accept();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(chatboxServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Accept Failed :3000");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new chatboxServer();
    }
}
```

It's still got issues, like using port 3000, but at least it compiles.

Comment: blimey, that weird input box has completely stuffed up the layout. Must be looking for <CR><LF> rather than just <LF>!!

Comment: Oh boy, now it's inserted a frame! Time to stop and leave it alone!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify that the chatboxServer() constructor is static.

for instance

```
private static chatboxServer() {
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: -1: A constructor cannot be static. It has to be bound to an object - that's the whole point of it!

Comment: Not only can constructor not be static, but every other attribute of the class would have to be static to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problematic line is the one below ;

```
s=ServerSocket.accept();
```

accept method of ServerSocket is not static method, it is instance method.. It should be corrected as below lines :

```
 ServerSocket s = null;
 Socket socket=null;
 try {                                    // Making server listen to port number 3000
      s=new ServerSocket(3000);
    } catch(IOException exc) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fr,"Cannot Listen :3000");
      return; 
    }
    try {

      socket=s.accept();
    } catch(IOException exc)
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fr,"Accept Failed :3000");
    }
```

Comment: my mistake, I had missed it. :) Thanks for the warning. :)

Comment: I think it's still wrong: `s.accept()` does not return a `ServerSocket`

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger: Thanks again for warning.

Comment: NullPointerException (s == null) if unable to listen on 3000

Answer (score 0):

You should write something like this:

```
ServerSocket server;
Socket socket;
 try {              
  server =new ServerSocket(3000);
  socket = server.accept();
 } catch(Exception exc) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"Cannot Listen & accept on port :3000");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a ServerSocket to s in one block, and use another ServerSocket also named s in the following block, this is the first problem. In the second block you call accept on the ServerSocket class instead of calling it on an instance...

Following code should be changed (just to make it work):

```
try { // Making server listen to port number 3000
      ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(3000);
    } catch(Exception exc) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"Cannot Listen :3000");
    }
    try {
      Socket s=null;
      s=ServerSocket.accept();
    } catch(Exception exc)
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"Accept Failed :3000");
    }
```

to:

```
 ServerSocket s;
try { // Making server listen to port number 3000
      s=new ServerSocket(3000);
    } catch(Exception exc) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"Cannot Listen :3000");
    }
    try {
      s.accept();
    } catch(Exception exc)
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"Accept Failed :3000");
    }
```